# Any chance to encrypt your project data of AutoPlay Media Studio with your own password when you export it as Web/Email Executable?

Tags: password-encryption, autoplay-media-studio

I'm looking for some ways to run my project in an executable archive and at the same time encrypt it with an specific password.
Why I wanna do this ? well, say you have some digital products to sell. the free version is an exe archive with your advertisement included. Now, say some customers need the product without the advertisement. well, if they pay for it they can receive the password of that archive to extract the contents inside.

I could simply have two versions of that product with and without the advertisement but since the size of the products is high, having two version is not the way to go.

So I thought it might be possible to kill two birds with one stone and I almost  came up with a solution...

Autoplay Media Studio can export in an exe archive and also encrypt it with a random password. Now just one step to make it... I'm just wondering to know if there's any possibility to use your own password...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own password options within AMS yes but you can not change the random password it uses no, you would have to create your own system to check it in the app like a reg file or a normal file or even have the user login via your server to check if there a valid user.

Also is also easy to decompile and hack so it would really depend on what your trying to do, if you just trying to do what android apps do hide ads if you pay a small amount you could do this I guess by creating a custom key basked on the computer what then creates a app key the user puts in and if they matched then remove the ads things like that, its very possible.

I would create two pages one with your ads placed on it and one without, I say this as AMS is horrible for moving objects in relation to another object. I would NOT build the password in to the software thought what ever you do.

I would say do a on-line php check and then tell the software its OK to view none ads, though this is still hackable at lest your not saving any passwords in the app since the app will request your password from php.

I would have your app when you want them to check for full version, --> user logs in to app --> app talks to server checks if there full version if true the server returns a code what checks with a code it just created before the check and if they match let the app view full mode, you could install a reg file or a simple file to say its full version with a encripted name so it can't just be coppied to another PC, but AMS is not the tool you really want if you want to keep your apps safe.